# Find the GCD of the minimum non-negative values of $a$, $b$ and $c$, given that the equation $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+1=0$ has real roots only.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

What is the GCD of the minimum non-negative values of $a$, $b$ and $c$, given that the equation $x^{4}+ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+1=0$ has real roots only?

Comment: is the leading term $x^4$?

Comment: Since there are three numbers $a,b,c$ this problem needs a definition of a measure to be minimal. For example is one to minimize the value of $\max(a,b,c)$, or maybe of $a+b+c$?